# Is there a shortcut to override methods in an Android Framework class in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Currently when overriding a method in e.g. an Activity in an Android Eclipse project I do:

Source > Override/Implement Methods > scroll list, check box, click OK.

Is there a shortcut for this with fewer steps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd>

All the keyboard shortcuts are discoverable in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for this keyboard shortcut, very helpful. What do you mean by "discoverable in the configuration"?

Comment: @PierreRymiortz The key mappings are searchable, it should show up in the configs.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Alt+Shift+S, V

Answer (score 1):

You can also start to type the method name and auto completion (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>) will also give you function you can override.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

1. Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Uncheck "Enable auto activation"
2. Preferences > General > Content Assist > Binding to Ctrl + Space (Set key bind) or Option + Space
3. type "on", then Ctrl + Space

Step 3 will shows methods you can override.

Disable auto activation will increase the performance of eclipse and bind key to content assist is much faster and useful.